# AppleScript for sending emails from a list

Tags: email, applescript

I have an AppleScript which starts a new email in Mail, and fills in the Body with the contents of a user-selected file.

The problem is that the first line of the body in the new email is always blank -- i.e. there's a line-break before the body from the user-selected file. No matter what I do, even if I hardcode the body into the script (e.g. "Hello world!") it starts on the second line of the email.

Can anyone please suggest a way to fix this?

```
property theToAddress : "john@example.com"
property theSubject : "Example subject"

set theTo to theToAddress
set theSubjectLine to theSubject

set theBody to choose file with prompt "Please select a file for the body of the email:"
set theMessageBody to read theBody as «class utf8»

tell application "Mail"
    set theNewMessage to make new outgoing message with properties {subject:theSubjectLine, content:theMessageBody, visible:true}
    tell theNewMessage
        make new to recipient with properties {address:theTo}
    end tell
end tell
```

Comment: FWIW, your script works as it should for me so perhaps there is some non-script related issue. Offhand, until you figure out what is causing the surplus line, you could conceivably do something directly to the empty paragraph later in the script, i.e. delete paragraph 1….

Comment: Thanks. It works perfectly on an older version of macOS but not the current. Strange! I'll give your suggestion a try. Cheers.

Comment: I should have noted that I'm running a Sierra, so a very old version. Hope it works out.

Comment: Yep — it works perfectly in Sierra but not whatever the latest one is called. Cheers again.